# In this situation we can shift path of integration?

Tags: complex-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

If $ \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}f(z)dz$ exists for any circle of radius $r>0$ centered at origin, the point $0$ is a singularity for $f$, and always the integral has the same value, say $k = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}f(z)dz,$ and $f$ is analitic outside $C$ with $|f(z)|\leq \dfrac{m}{|z|}$ ($m$ constant), is true that we can shift path of integration from $C$ to the some line $Re(z)= \gamma$ using Cauchy's Theorem?

My doubt arises because of the lemma 7.1 in the PAZY book (Semigroups of linear operators and applications to partial differential equations), which shows that the integral exists for any circle centered on the origin and then says that it is possible to use Cauchy's Theorem to change the path of integration from a circle to a line. Is that really true? I know it can be exchanged for another closed contour, more the way it did I’ve never seen.

Comment: Since $f(z) \mathrm d z$ has a possible residu at infinity, such an integral at least requires a very careful definition. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

Comment: since $1/|z|$ is not integrable at infinity, you need some extra symmetry at the least - in the book mentioned, check exactly all the hypothesis given as the respective function may have some symmetries (eg is conjugate invariant $f(\bar z)=\bar f(z)$)

Comment: @Conrad in fact, the $ f $ function is the product of an exponential with the resolving operator, and I was able to explicitly verify that it is possible to change the integral of the circle to the line segment, but I have not yet been able to change the entire line. I can do this as long as it is true that the integral of the rest of the line is zero. Is this true because the member is analytic outside the circle? the problem I'm finding to see this is that the complement of the circle is not simply connected, so you can't use Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: you use the Cauchy theorem for the domain bounded by line and circle (as long as circle is not intersecting with the line, you can think of the line as a circle passing through infinity, so if the function has no singularity at $\infty$ you are good - by Cauchy result is zero, so integral on the line is same as on the circle - as long as you can show the integral on the line converges - you need conditional convergence only in general though of course one has to be more careful in the conditional case

Comment: Try it with $f(z)=1/z$, and tell me what you find.